# looking for (N) steps GUI kind of thing

Tags: user-interface

i dont sure if this question is for this group but i don't know where to ask
im looking for GUI examples that gives the user for example make X in 4 steps 
kind of GUI especial for none teachi folks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like a Dialog Wizard type interface?

The idea of a wizard is you have a single window where you can step through a number of frames containing different selections using a next button and a back button to go back and change selections? Sometimes you have a finish button to use the default selections on the remaining frames.

What language and GUI toolkit are you using???

Comment: im using Qt and yes wizard is the word